# Translation system of arabic to english in the right format

Tags: translation, tokenize, arabic, moses

I am setting up a Moses Machine Translation System from Arabic to English.
In which format should the arabic text file be, should I input the text file as it is or should I reverse the word order of each sentence?
In other words, does the Moses tokenizer need arabic reversed or as is?

Comment: Did you get anything for your question? i am pretty much interested to know if you had any luck with it, i would be thankful if you could just post your findings here.

Answer (score 1):

No, it should not be reversed.